# Are all Non-Diagonalizable square matrices Defective?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Do all Non-Diagonalizable square matrices have the property of not having complete set of eigenvectors, i.e. they are Defective?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ - matrix. Then: $A$ is diagonalizable $\iff A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.